# Connect apache and coldfusion 10 using mod_proxy_ajp

Tags: apache, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm trying to setup my local development environment and I'm only missing one piece of the puzzle.

I was able to successfully install the following on my Mac OSX 10.7.5 x86_x64
XAMPP - http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html
ColdFusion 10 - Developer Edition

Both are running fine. I was able to pull up localhost (Apache) and localhost:8500 (ColdFusion) - my ajp connector port is 8012

Now I want to be able to pass the request to my ColdFusion from Apache using mod_proxy_ajp.

I created an index.cfm file on the wwwroot/cf directory of ColdFusion, enabled the NameVirtualHost and created a VirtualHost directive in Apache that looks like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
<Location "/cf">
Allow from all
ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8012/
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

After restarting everything, I get a 503 error.
Any help or pointers is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

check your CF logs:
`{cf_root}/cfusion/logs/coldfusion-error.log`

You probably have something like this in the log:

```
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor getRealPathFromServer
SEVERE: Error in getRealPathFromConn
java.io.IOException: Socket read failed
```

So mod_proxy_ajp is passing the request to Tomcat, but Tomcat can't read it.

Have you tried configuring with mod_jk instead?

http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion10-apache-manual-connector-configuration.html

Might not be the way you want to configure it, but it should get you up and running.